# How to read multiple WAV files just by giving a folder

Tags: python, file-io, wav

I have about 30 `.wav` files in a folder `C:\Users\Maheswar.reddy\Desktop\NLP\wav_folder`. I am trying to write code to read all the `.wav` files in the folder, but I couldn't do it. How can I read all the files at once, given the name of the folder?

I was able to read a single file giving the path now I want to read all the files at once.

Comment: What are you hoping to do with these wave files?  Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?  You tagged both.  What code do you have?  Are you running Jupyter locally, or on a server?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You mentioned that you tried but it didn't work: please include the code anyways (we require a [mre]). You also want to read the files, but that isn't specific enough. Please [edit] your question to add details and the code that is required for a high quality question. Thank you. Also see [ask] from the help center.

Comment: Okay, so what is the **question**? Do you know how to read a file? Do you know how to figure out what wav files are in the folder? Do you know how to repeat code? If you put those steps together, why does it not solve the problem? What does "I couldn't do it" **actually mean**? *How* did you try, and *what happened* when you tried it, and *how is that different* from what is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you mean by "read all the files at once". Here's an example using a [pathlib glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) that you can extend to process the files sequentially:

```
from pathlib import Path
base_path = Path(r"C:\Users\Maheswar.reddy\Desktop\NLP\wav_folder")
for wav_file_path in base_path.glob("*.wav"):
    print(f"WAV File: {wav_file_path}")
    # do something, e.g. with open(wav_file_path) as wav_file:
```

If you want to process all of the files concurrently, you'll need to look at [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html?highlight=threading#module-threading) or [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#module-multiprocessing).

Comment: Hi @Timrobert and others I was using jupyter notebook and I was able to read a single file but I dont know How to read all the files at a time by giving the folder and I am was doing this for sentimental analysis